# How to customize Metro Style ListView Scrollbar

Tags: listview, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a `ListView` control in my `Javascript` Metro Style App. When the OS detect that you are using touch, it will show a very thin scroll bar. When the OS detects that you are using Mouse, it will show a thick scroll bar.

My question is, is there any way that I can customize, style or hide the scroll bar in the list view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh996962.aspx There are a lot of options for styling the scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful! By any chances you know how to change the size of the scroll bar?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean with "size" but I think, there is no option to change the width or the height of the scrollbar. Therefore you need to use an external JS-library like @maxhud posted.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at the moment, but it may come in a future release.

If you really needed you could use something like this: http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jScrollbar/